# find index of row matching a given criteria

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have the following list (`nodes`):

```
nodeID, x, y, z=row
```

I want to find the index of the row which `row[0]==nodeAID`.

My code is:

```
nindF=[line[0].index(nodeAID) for line in nodes]
```

but it gives me the error: `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

Comment: is nodeAID supposed to be "nodeAID"? or is it a variable you define somewhere?

Comment: @RyanSaxe: Sorry, yes it is a string.

Comment: what are the dimensions of nodes?

Comment: It is like `4*300`: 4 columns and 300 rows

Comment: and you're trying to get a list that is a list of the row numbers in which the first column of that row is `"nodeAID"`?

Comment: Yes, basically is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nindF = [index for index, line in enumerate(nodes) if line[0].find(nodeAID) >= 0]
```

This will return a list of indexes of all the lines that start with nodeAID.
If you only care about the index of the first line that starts with nodeAID then:

```
nindF = [index for index, line in enumerate(nodes) if line[0].find(nodeAID) >= 0][0]
```